# Applying class styles with jquery, but not all styles are applying

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting some beginner manipulation of applying a CSS class style using jquery. I am setting two class attributes, color and font size. Both Defined under the class .zebra, yet only the color is being applied.

Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('Script is tied in!');
$('#lion').addClass('zebra');
});
```

CSS

```
p {
color: #CC34H8;
font-size: 100px;
}

.zebra {
color: #2FB51D;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

EJS, still basically straight HTML markup at this point

```
<body>
hello hello
<p> hi </p>
<div id="lion">
    <p> hey hey </p>
</div>
</body>
```

The color attribute from the CSS is changing, but the font is not (still displaying as the 100px from the original `<p>` defined style. Why is only one of the attributes being affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is right except just one thing.

You are applying the class `.zebra` to the `div.lion` not the tag `p` itself, so the text inside tag `p` get the `color` from the parent `div` and for `font-size` from it's css.

that's why only `color` is only changed.

change your code into this:

```
$('#lion p').addClass('zebra');//notice " p".
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the class to `#lion` but the `font-size` property is being overwritten by the `p` tag.

The following jQuery line will work for you:

```
$('#lion p').addClass('zebra');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu4ts/).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change `class` for `<p>` tag and it still have `font-size:100px`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lion p').addClass('zebra');
});
```